# Do not show splash screen on return from settings activity

Tags: android-actionbar, settings, splash-screen, back-button, main-activity

I have an app that loads a `SplashScreen` as a full screen `Dialog` that closes on loading the `MainActivity`. However, the problem here is that whenever I open my `SettingsActivity` and come back to the `MainActivity` in the following ways:

1. on Android back button press, the `SplashScreen` wont be displayed. So no problems here!
2. on up navigation on `ActionBar` is pressed, the `SplashScreen` is displayed again. This is the problem, I don't want the `SplashScreen` displayed again.

Here's my `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setPreferencesFromSettings();
    if (splashScreenDisplayed) {showSplash(); splashScreenDisplayed = false; }
    //...DO SOMETHING ELSE...//
}

public void showSplash() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();

    final Handler handler  = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }; handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3500);
}

@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    splashScreenDisplayed = false;
    setPreferencesFromSettings();
}
```

And the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="Settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tried a few other posts however they didn't work for me. I know that I am missing a line of code or something somewhere, I spent hours looking at the code again and again and I couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `SharedPrefernces` to store a key for `SplashNotDisplayed` and reading it everytime `MainActivity` is loaded.

I set the Key to `True` in `myapplication.java` as this is only loaded once for every app instance and once the splash is displayed I set the key to `False` and the next time if `MainActivity` is loaded, SplashNotDisplayed key will be false and it wont be displayed again.

in `MyApplication.java`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor shPrefEditor = prefs.edit();
shPrefEditor.putBoolean("splashNotDisplayed", true);
shPrefEditor.apply();
```

in `MainActivity.java` I changed the implementation from this

```
if (splashScreenDisplayed) {showSplash(); splashScreenDisplayed = false; }
```

to this:

```
boolean splashNotDisplayed = prefs.getBoolean("splashNotDisplayed", true);
if (splashNotDisplayed) {
    showSplash();
    shPrefEditor.putBoolean("splashNotDisplayed", false);
    shPrefEditor.apply();
}
```